# How to configure a Bean prototype scoped provider to use session information on Bean creation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to provide beans based on session information every time the proxy is acessed to obtain the instance. How I can do that?

For now I tried the following. For example:

The first class defines a session scoped bean.

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class BeanSession implements Serializable {

    private Serializable rootState;

    public <T extends Serializable> T getRootState() {
        return (T) rootState;
    }

    public void setRootState(Serializable rootState) {
        this.rootState = rootState;
    }
}
```

The second class has some logic related to their domain and also knows how to provide the information. The bean must be a created every time because the information can change during the thread processing. Therefore, every time the `Attribute1` is acessed I will be sure to get the bean with fresh information.

```java
@Service
public class Attribute1Service {

    @Resource
    private BeanSession beanSession;

    public void setDefaultValue() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        configuration.getAttribute1().setValue("VALUE 1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Attribute1 attribute1() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        return configuration.getAttribute1();
    }

}
```

Finally, the third class declares the `attribute1` as dependency to execute their own logic.

```java
@Service
public class Attribute2Service {

    @Resource
    private BeanSession beanSession;

    @Resource
    private Processor processor;

    @Resource
    private Attribute1 attribute1;

    public void defineAttribute2() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        String value = processor.getValue(configuration, attribute1);
        configuration.getAttribute2().setValue(value);
    }

    public void defineAttribute3() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        String value = processor.getValue(configuration, attribute1);
        configuration.getAttribute3().setValue(value);
    }

}
```

However, the problem is that during `attribute1` creation I am getting the following error:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Attribute2Service': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attribute1' defined in class path resource [Attribute1Service.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [String]: Factory method 'attribute1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.beanSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
...
```

I don't want to access `attribute1` information from `beanSession` on `Attribute2Service` because it will create a hard coupling between the information providers and consumers.

Comment: Add `javax.inject` dependency and use `Provider<BeanSession>` and when needed do `provider.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the insights given by Alexander.Furer. I created my own scope and managed it to call the bean provider to have the fresh bean in every access of `Attribute1` methods.

To this, I extended the following Scope:

```java
// Register scope as "runtime"
public class RuntimeScope implements Scope {

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        return objectFactory.getObject();
    }

    ...
}
```

The new `Attribute1` service:

```java
@Service
public class Attribute1Service {

    @Resource
    private BeanSession beanSession;

    public void setDefaultValue() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        configuration.getAttribute1().setValue("VALUE 1");
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "runtime", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Attribute1 attribute1() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        return configuration.getAttribute1();
    }

}
```

The consumer `Attribute2`service:

```java
@Service
public class Attribute2Service {

    @Resource
    private BeanSession beanSession;

    @Resource
    private Processor processor;

    @Resource
    private Attribute1 attribute1;

    public void defineAttribute2() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        String value = processor.getValue(configuration, attribute1.getValue()); // Will call Attribute1 service to require the fresh bean
        configuration.getAttribute2().setValue(value);
    }

    public void defineAttribute3() {
        Configuration configuration = beanSession.getRootState();
        String value = processor.getValue(configuration, attribute1.getValue()); // Will call Attribute1 service to require the fresh bean
        configuration.getAttribute3().setValue(value);
    }

}
```

The problem I wasn't seeing is that Attribute1 should be a proxy to handle the bean instantiation. Therefore, creating my own scope I can guarantee that accesses to attribute1 (made by `Attribute2Service` with `attribute1.getValue()`) methods will create a fresh bean (provided by `Attribute1Service`).

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all - your attribute1 bean gets created during app initialization (via session scoped bean) but there is no thread bound with request. You should proxy your attribute1 bean as well because you are injecting it to singleton (attribute 2 service. )

Comment: Yes, the problem is clear. Could you preset the solution with some source code?

Comment: As I said, attribute1 should be proxied, and since it gets created via session scoped bean, it will be accessible from web request bound thread only.

Comment: Sorry, based on your answer I could detail better my question. I will edit it and create the answer based on the insights you gave me.